# Unable to install PCoIP Client

Tags: remote-access

I am new to Ubuntu, and I am attempting to install PCoIP Software Client in Ubuntu 20.04. But, I am getting the following error.

```
sudo wget -O teradici-repo-latest.deb https://downloads.teradici.com/ubuntu/teradici-repo-$(lsb_release -cs)-latest.deb
--2021-06-22 15:52:20--  https://downloads.teradici.com/ubuntu/teradici-repo-focal-latest.deb
Resolving downloads.teradici.com (downloads.teradici.com)... 52.25.54.15
Connecting to downloads.teradici.com (downloads.teradici.com)|52.25.54.15|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-06-22 15:52:21 ERROR 404: Not Found.*
```

But I installed it with the same script in Ubuntu 18.04 (VM on Windows 10 Pro | Hyper-V)

I got the above script from the following web page.
https://www.teradici.com/web-help/pcoip_client/linux/20.04/installation/install_client_ubuntu/
Kindly assist me to fix this issue.
Thanks you.

Comment: The error message is correct. Your Ubuntu version is `focal` (20.04) but the only packages available are for `bionic` (18.04) and `xenial` (16.04), as can be seen [here](https://downloads.teradici.com/ubuntu/). You could try downloading the 18.04 version by replacing `$(lsb_release -cs)` by `bionic` in the download command.

Comment: Hi @Jos,
Thanks for your reply.
Ho, I see, but the link says it can be installed in 20.04. That's why I tried.
Anyway thanks once again.